# Visual or intuitive proof of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, visualization, proof-without-words

It is well known that the alternate sum of the reciprocals of the odd numbers adds up to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. That is
$$1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
A proof can be obtained by using geometric series and termwise integration to compute the Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ and then evaluating it at $x=1$:
$$\arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}\Rightarrow\arctan(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\Rightarrow\arctan(1)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$ and now use that $\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

> Now, is there any visual (geometric) or other sort of intuitive proof on why this should be true?

An example of the sort of visual proof I'm thinking would be something like starting by taking a quarter circle inscribed in an area 1 square and alternatingly adding and substrating squares of areas 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, etc. from the original square in a way that we keep approximating the quarter circle.

Still, any other intuitive proof on why the alternate sum of reciprocals of odd numbers is related to $\pi$ would be great to have.

Comment: Maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lI9PvDNxSQ) is helpful? (Some details are skipped)

Comment: @user170231 I don't consider the transformation at 00:39 to 00:45 obvious at all. We have a section from the circle mysteriously transformed into some concave shape. How...?

Comment: Some suggestions. Since we're dealing with an infinite series, if we are to interpret it geometrically, we would reasonably expect to need some geometric structure comprising an infinite sequence of parts. Appealing candidates might include self-similar shapes, Riemann sums, integrals etc. So we could use a self-similar structure similar to [that shown](https://trigonography.com/?p=842) by MSE @user409 (Blue) on their excellent website to represent the arctan function (of which pi is a special value) (1/2)

Comment: Or we could take inspiration from [Yiorgos S. Smyrlis' answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2253506/161490) to consider that the Leibniz formula in its general form, as a power series in $x$ as equivalent to the integral $\int 1/{x^2+1}$ (provided we are happy with the power rule (2/2)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. This video goes quite deep into it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00w8gu2aL-w

Comment: +1 (also) to the posted question.  Very interesting question, nicely presented.